# Zipping uneven arrays in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, zip

I have two uneven arrays:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = ['d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
```

I'd like to bind them so that the object returned looks like this:

```
result = [[nil, 1], [nil, 2], [nil, 3], ["d", 4], ["e", 5], ["f", 6], ["g", 7],
["h", 8], ["i", 9], ["j", 10]]
```

The `zip` method would not work, as it does the opposite by lining up elements to the front. So far I have:

```
def bind(a,b,ac=a.count,bc=b.count)
  distance = ac - bc < 0 ? bc - ac : ac - bc
  min = ac > bc ? b : a
  max = ac > bc ? a : b 
  distance.times { min.unshift(nil) }
  return min.zip(max)
end
```

Does ruby have a method to resolve this (or a quicker way to go about it)?

Comment: `ac=a.count,bc=b.count` should be turned into a part of the method body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `a.size >= b.size`:

```
([nil]*(a.size-b.size)).concat(b).zip(a)
  #=> [[nil, 1], [nil, 2], [nil, 3], ["d", 4], ["e", 5],
  #    ["f", 6], ["g", 7], ["h", 8], ["i", 9], ["j", 10]]
```

or

```
[([nil]*(a.size-b.size)).concat(b), a].transpose
```

The methods [Enumerable#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) and [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) are *[yin and yang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yin_and_yang)* when the two arrays are the same size.

Comment: I like this one, but must say this is a time where one line would be a bit too confusing. Hard to understand what is happening imo. I ouwld split it in two. `extra_elements = [nil]*(a.size-b.size); (extra_elements+b).zip(a)`

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
a.reverse.zip(b.reverse).reverse.map(&:reverse)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although very close to Cary's solution. I find this more readable.

```
missing_elements = Array.new(a.size-b.size)
p (missing_elements+b).zip(a)
```